# In a multiple linear regression model, how do I test the null hypothesis that multiple coefficients are equal to zero simultaneously?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, simultaneous-test

For example, if I have `Y = b0 + b1X1 + b2X2 + b3X3 + b4X4`, I want to test H0: b1 = b3 = 0, at alpha = 0.05.

I ran an `lm` model in R and got the p-values for each coefficient and the overall F statistic, but I'm not sure what to do to test them simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, you want to know if the coefficients are equal to $0$.  A model where the coefficients are $0$ is the same as a model that does not include those variables.  Thus, you can perform a nested model test of a reduced model without those variables versus a full model that includes all the variables.

In a linear model context, that is called an $F$-change test, or $R^2$-change test, because you can compute the test value from the $F$ (or $R^2$) statistics from the two models (it is also sometimes called a 'multiple partial $F$ test, and by a dozen other names).  I show a version of the formula here: [Testing for moderation with continuous vs. categorical moderators](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33090/7290).  In a non-linear context (e.g., a logistic regression model), a likelihood ratio test can be used.  More generally, testing multiple parameters at the same time is called a simultaneous test or a chunk test.

Concretely, to do this in `R` you would do something like:

```
m.full    = lm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4)
m.reduced = lm(Y~X2+X4)
anova(m.reduced, m.full)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will illustrate for models with one and two regressors, the generalization to four variables should be obvious.

```
library(lmtest)
y <- rnorm(100)
x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)

reg1 <- lm(y~x1)
reg2 <- lm(y~x1+x2)
waldtest(reg1,reg2)
```

So, load the `lmtest` package (the next three lines just create some example data), run the restricted regession `reg1`, the unrestricted one `reg2` and let `waldtest` do the comparison for you.

For my random numbers, I get the following output:

```
Wald test

Model 1: y ~ x1
Model 2: y ~ x1 + x2
  Res.Df Df      F Pr(>F)
1     98                 
2     97  1 0.0178 0.8942
```

Thus, the null that $\beta_2=0$ cannot be rejected at $\alpha=0.05$, as the $p$-value `Pr(>F)` is way larger. This is not surprising in view of how I generated the data: there s no relationship between the `x` and `y`.

Comment: There is also the package `car` which allows to do the test without setting up the restricted model by oneself, e.g. for `b1 = b3 = 0`: `car::linearHypothesis(reg, c("x1", "x3"), c(0,0), test = "F")`