# How to compare the regression coefficients of two independent variables between two groups

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding

I want to test whether the coefficients of two independent variables ($x_1, x_2$) are different in two groups.

I know I can use a dummy variable $d$ which equals $1$ for group $1$ and equals $0$ for group $2$, and then get the regression model $y=β_0+β_1d+β_2x+β_3xd$ to see whether $β_3$ significantly differs from $0$.  But in this model, there is only one independent variable $x$.  How can I use a dummy variable when I have more than one independent variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need two interaction terms.  Your model would be:
$$
y=β_0+β_1d+β_2x_1+β_3x_2 + \beta_4x_1d + \beta_5x_2d
$$
From there, if you wanted to test them individually, you would just inspect the $t$-test that came standardly with your output for each of the two interactions.  If you wanted to test them both together, you would drop the two interaction terms and fit a nested model.  Then you would perform a nested model test.

Comment: Thanks so much.  And may I know more about the nested model test?  Is it to test whether the model B: y=β0+β1d+β2x1+β3x2+β4x1d+β5x2d is better than model A: y=β0+β2x1+β3x2?

Comment: @moonstar, yes, you take your "A" as the null, & see if you should reject that in favor of "B". If the test is significant, there is information in those 2 interaction terms (somewhere). Regarding nested model tests, it may help to read my answer here: [esting for moderation with continuous vs. categorical moderators](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33090/7290).