# How does step function selects best linear Models which includes polynomial effects and interaction effects in R?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, model-selection, bic

I try to find "best" linear models with continuous and categorical covariables with Interaction Effect by BIC. The continuous covariables should have a quadratic effect on the response variable.

Additional to that, I want to extract the significant covariates from the full model by the following rule:

*- If  $Covariable_1*Covariable_i !=0$   for one of the i Covariates, then Covariates_1 and Covariates_i remain in the model (i.e also if just the first order term of the polynomial is significant wrt. p-value then we include also the quadratic term), also all significant interactions
 - If $Covariates_1*Covariates_i==0$ for all i then we exlude this Interaction Term and look at the maineffects of covariate_1: if there is no effect at all, then we remove this covariate.*

Does this rule make any sense?

I wonder whether the step function in R considers this rule automatically and if not, whether there is any procedures/methods to this in R.

How would you start and find the best linear model with polynomial effect if you had to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this rule make any sense?

It's sensible in empirical modelling to follow the Principle of Marginality: See [Venables (1998), "Exegeses on linear models", S-Plus Users' Conference, Washington DC](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf), [Including the interaction but not the main effects in a model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009), [Do all interaction terms need their individual terms in a regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27724), & [Does triple interaction need to include all main effect variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133959).

> I wonder whether the step function in R considers this rule automatically and if not, whether there is any procedures/methods to this in R.

Don't know about `step`—check the manual or code.

> How would you start and find the best linear model with polynomial effect if you had to choose?

If I had to use some automatic method for model selection (& I'd rather not—see [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836), & [Flom & Cassell (2007), "Stopping stepwise", NESUG](http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug07/sa/sa07.pdf)), I'd use [LASSO](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html) in almost all situations that come up in practice (see [What are modern, easily used alternatives to stepwise regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13686)). Otherwise, I'd treat it as a matter of deciding how best to spend degrees of freedom in modelling curvilinear relationships: see the [hand-outs](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RmS) for Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* course, §4.1.

Comment: I love CV answers that reference other CV contributors.

Comment: @user777: Thanks! I hadn't thought, but that's two in one answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As far as I can see, the step function  automatically works according to my rule - so at least this question is solved.

Comment: You're welcome. I had a quick look, & `step` calls `drop1` & `add1` - the help pages for these say they do respect the Marginality Principal (though that'll depend on you using the formula interface I suppose).