# What does maintaining marginality mean in stepwise regression?

Tags: r, model-selection, stepwise-regression

I was reading the [helpfile](https://rdrr.io/cran/MASS/man/dropterm.html) for the `dropterm` function in the R MASS package, which is one of the main building blocks of the `stepAIC` function (at least for backwards stepwise regression.) The aim of this function is to identify a variable to remove from a model by sequentially considering models that drop one variable.

In the helpfile, it states:

> Try fitting all models that differ from the current model by dropping a single term, maintaining marginality.

What does maintaining marginality mean in this context? Is it a special treatment of interactions specified in the model formula, e.g. by dropping interactions first before dropping the interacting variables?

Related:

[How does step function selects best linear Models which includes polynomial effects and interaction effects in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135779/how-does-step-function-selects-best-linear-models-which-includes-polynomial-effe/135783#135783)

Comment: I suspect it's the [principle of marginality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that, if you have an interaction, all the lower terms in that interaction are also included in the model. If your model includes "foo:bar", then your model will also include "foo" and "bar" as independent effects.

As mentioned below in comments, this means that any interaction would be dropped before any of its components is dropped.

Comment: Does this mean foo:bar is dropped first before considering foo and bar to be dropped?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. Y

Comment: I will accept your answer if a combination of my comment and your comment is incorporated into it.