# Is it possible to use several interaction terms?

Tags: regression, modeling, interaction

I came across this equation when I was reading the article:
$$\textrm{Y} = \alpha + \textrm{X}_1  (\beta_0 + \beta_1 \textrm{X}_2 + \beta_2 \textrm{X}_3) + \varepsilon$$

At least, I can understand the latter two variables in the parenthesis: both $\textrm{X}_2$ and $\textrm{X}_3$ affect $\textrm{Y}$ with $\textrm{X}_1$.
However, there are several things do not make sense to me:

1. How can I interpret $\textrm{X}_1 * \beta_0$? Is it fine to say constant affects $\textrm{Y}$ with $\textrm{X}_1$?
2. When we use interaction term, don't we have to include the variables with no interaction? Shouldn't be the equation like this? $$\textrm{Y} = \alpha + \textrm{X}_1  (\beta_0 + \beta_1 \textrm{X}_2 + \beta_2 \textrm{X}_3) + \beta_3 + \beta_4 \textrm{X}_2 + \beta_5 \textrm{X}_3    +  \varepsilon$$

Comment: Is $X_1$ a binary variable or something else?

Comment: It is an interval variable. In the article, it is defined as "effective number of elective parties".

Comment: Set $X_1$ to zero & the model reduces to $Y=\alpha+\varepsilon$: there is no relationship between $Y$ & $X_2$,  or between $Y$ & *$X_3$ for this special value of $X_1$. The general issues with such constraints are discussed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133959/17230), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27724/17230), & [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/17230); you'll have to include some context to allow anyone to say whether it makes sense in this particular case. (BTW the alternative you suggest appears to have an unnecessary $\beta_3$ on its own.)

Comment: It may help to understand the meaning and purpose of the model. Since $X_1$ is some kind of count or proportion, the model seems to propose that $Y$ is the product of two quantities (plus an additive offset and error), which might make perfectly good sense as a count weighted by something else or as a proportion of something.