# How to limit interaction terms in logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interaction

I am running a logistic regression model with 5 predictor variables. I would like to include an interaction term in this model. However, when I use the formula:

```
glm(Indroad~A+B+C+D+E + (A*B*C*D*), family=binomial(link="logit"), data=sub.data)
```

or the formula:

```
glm(Indroad ~ A*B*C*D*E, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=sub.data)
```

I am given an output that includes all possible combinations for the interaction term (e.g., A:B, A:C). I am really only interested in the terms `A:B:C` and `A:B:C:D:E`.

Is there anyway to limit the interactions that R runs? I have tried without success to use the update command, and have tried to run the same formula with - unwanted interaction terms (both without success).

Comment: Why not just create two separate variables that are equal to the interactions you want, and use those?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! See `?formula` & https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133959/17230.

Comment: I agree with what @Scortchi points you to in the link to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133959/28500). Please consider whether you should be looking at these high-order interactions without considering the lower-order interactions. That's an important statistical (as opposed to coding) issue.

Answer (score 4):

(*This is mostly a question about how to use R, and thus off topic here.*)

In R, if you use `*` in a formula, it will automatically insert all interaction terms and main effect terms below the interaction you specify.  To specify a only specific interaction term, you need to use `:` (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models)).  That is,

```
glm(Indroad~A+B+C+D+E + A:B:C + A:B:C:D:E, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=sub.data)
```

---

That said, the statistical issue here is that you almost certainly should not include an interaction term (`A:B:C:D:E`) without including the lower level terms beneath it in the hierarchy.  For more on this, see [Including the interaction but not the main effects in a model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/7290) (of which this is really a duplicate).