# Treatment of main terms when adding interaction terms to linear regression

Tags: regression, interaction

If I have a model that is Y~A+B, where only A is significant (low p-value). After adding an interaction term to form a new model Y~A+B+(A*B), B remains not significant but the interaction term (A*B) is significant.

I have read that "Note that, an interaction term is added into the model when the main term is already in the model. For example, we should not have the term $x_1x_2$ in the model if there is no term $x_2$ or $x_1$."

Would this be an issue since I am not dropping the not significant term (in this case B)? Do I fit Y~A or Y~A + B + (A*B) since I don't think it is appropriate to fit Y~A + A*B?

Comment: Welcome! Not only *should* you fit the interaction model with the corresponding main effects, but you will often be *forced to* in practice. In some software packages, including a product term in a model automatically results in the estimation of the main effects. Now, just because you *should not* omit the main effect does not mean you cannot in practice. The interpretation or A*B will be different if you omit A or B. I think a lot of ground was covered in this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27724/do-all-interactions-terms-need-their-individual-terms-in-regression-model).

Answer (score 0):

**You should fit Y ~ A + B + AB.**

A model with two main factors should include the interaction term because we need to know how to interpret the main factor results.

If the interaction term is not-significant then the main effects can be interpreted directly (they are constant). Different levels of factor A always have the same effect.

But if the interaction term is significant, then the effect of factor A depends on the level of factor B (the effect of factor A is not constant).