# Testing whether dividing independent variable into groups is rational

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, interaction, f-test

Let's imagine that we have three variables - $Y, X_1$ and $X_2$, where $Y$ is dependent continuous variable, $X_1$ is continuous variable and $X_2$ is discrete variable with two factors - $0$ and $1$. I'm interested in linear model $Y \sim  X_1$, however I want to think of statistical test which will determine whether its necessary to divide $X_1$ into two categories with respect to $X_2$.

**My idea**

My idea was to create first model $Y \sim X_1 + X_1 \cdot 1_{\{X_2 = 0\}} $
and second model $Y \sim X_1$.

Since those two models are nested, I can compare them using F - test to check whether reduction is rational i.e. if sum of squares error ($\sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2$) is significantly different.

Is this make any sense to you? Is there any more popular way how it can be done?

Comment: *discrete variable with two factors - 0 and 1* it would be more standard terminology to say *with two levels*. Also, what you really are doing with the second model is to introduce the *interaction* of $X_1$  with $X_2$.  Then you would usually also include the direct effect of $X_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using some non-standard terminology (a more descriptive title would also help). Your two models can be written as
$$
\begin{align}
\label{I}\tag{I} Y_i&= \alpha +\beta X_{1i} + \epsilon_i \\
\label{II'}\tag{II'} Y_i&=\alpha+\beta X_{1i} \cdot \mathbb{1}(X_{2i}=0)+\epsilon_i
\end{align} $$
but here equation $\eqref{II'}$ is a version of the interaction model (assuming the factor $X_2$ is binary-coded 0/1)
$$
\label{II}\tag{II} Y_i=\alpha+\beta X_{1i} + \gamma_0 X_{2i} +\gamma_1 X_{1i}X_{2i} + \epsilon_i
$$
and usually you would prefer $\eqref{II}$ to your $\eqref{II'}$, as it violates the *heredity principle*, that usually one should include all main effects included in an interaction. But of course, your case could be an exception ... see the former posts [Do all interactions terms need their individual terms in regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27724/do-all-interactions-terms-need-their-individual-terms-in-regression-model/28056#28056)   and   [Including the interaction but not the main effects in a model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/including-the-interaction-but-not-the-main-effects-in-a-model).

**Then to your question**  Modulo the above, your idea makes sense. The models are nested, so the F-test is a good way to compare the models.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are basically asking whether $\textbf{X}_2$ is a "usefull" variable (and/or its interactions). You use words like "rational" or "necessary", but these words have meaning in the context of some defined goal.

The role $\textbf{X}_2$ *ought* to play depends on this goal. One goal might be maximizing $R^2$, in all likelihood adding $\textbf{X}_2$ and interaction terms will help you further this goal, unless $\textbf{X}_2$ is entirely uncorrelated with $Y$. On the other hand, maybe you are interested in a particular causal effect, like the effect of $\textbf{X}_1$ on $Y$. In this case including $\textbf{X}_2$ depends on $Cov(X_2,X_1)$ and $Cov(X_ 2, error)$, and does not need necessarily help you in your goal.