# What are the pros and cons of standardizing variable in presence of an interaction?

Tags: standardization

I put this question because while reading the benefits of  standardizing explanatory variables or not, I read *good but contrasting* opinions about standardizing when there are interaction in the model.

Some talk about how problems of collinearity are removed when standardizing (e.g. [Collinearity diagnostics problematic only when the interaction term is included](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60476/collinearity-diagnostics-problematic-only-when-the-interaction-term-is-included#61022)), which is basically the case of my GLMM. However, others claim that standard errors and p-values of interactions of standardized models are not reliable... (e.g.[Variables are often adjusted (e.g. standardised) before making a model - when is this a good idea, and when is it a bad one?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/variables-are-often-adjusted-e-g-standardised-before-making-a-model-when-is) or http://quantpsy.org/interact/interactions.htm)

So, any ideas on what is the right thing to do?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please have a look at the possible duplicate & if you're still in doubt edit your question to explain how.

Comment: "standard errors and p-values of interactions of standardized models are not reliable"? That is not true as far as I know. SE and p-values are equivalent between standardized and un-standardized models.