# Variance Inflation Factors are incredibly high for t1 - can I use this model

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, interaction, variance-inflation-factor

I am building a model to explain performance in one time period to another.  I have my variables and then I have an interaction effect for those variables in the second time period.

Using this data, I can then say what is the change in performance due to the change in these values ( this is split by the change in average in t0 and t1, and also the change in beta coefficients).

The challenge I have is that many values in t0 are significant (and have acceptable VIF).  However when I look at the corresponding coefficients and their VIFs, they are incredible high - some over 100 and some over 500.

My simple question, can I use these values that are significant in t0 but have very high VIF in t1?  What are the dangers of using them?
[image: Output_from_SAS]
Part 2;
I have looked into using lasso to select the model.  The challenge there is that it stops at 2 variables, when I can see that more are significant, and the best manual model I can build doesn't come through.  I am also struggling to formulate this in SAS as I have when I have 3 variables ( var 1 var 2 var 3 and their corresponding interactions (int 1 int 2 int 3), lasso picks var1 and int 2 which doesn't work.  I add this as an additional element, and can understand if you cannot answer it and I need to repost it in stack overflow.  The first part is more important to me right now.

Answer (score 1):

So through reading and testing my data, I have found that interactions do generally generate very high VIFs and I can effectively ignore them.
This is backed up through this article, found through this post
[Robinson& Schumacher](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.620.5853&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[Collinearity diagnostics problematic only when the interaction term is included](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60476/collinearity-diagnostics-problematic-only-when-the-interaction-term-is-included)

The paper talks about running separate (simple) regressions without interactions to validate the betas that you receive, and check the significance of the variables.  In my case, I ran them for t0 and t1. Running these myself is what has convinced me that generally I am on the right track - though I am struggling with what to do with this particular data set (I am running this in different areas), but this is a different issue.

I am answering my own question as I hope it will help others later when they come to this issue.