# If you standardize X, must you always standardize y?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear, standardization

Related reading:

- [When conducting multiple regression, when should you center your predictor variables & when should you standardize them?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia)
- [When and how to use standardized explanatory variables in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/when-and-how-to-use-standardized-explanatory-variables-in-linear-regression)
- [Variables are often adjusted (e.g. standardised) before making a model - when is this a good idea, and when is it a bad one?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/variables-are-often-adjusted-e-g-standardised-before-making-a-model-when-is)
- [Follow-up question: When should you center your data & when should you standardize?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110171/follow-up-question-when-should-you-center-your-data-when-should-you-standardi)

Background:

I am comparing the effectiveness of various forms of linear regression machine learning, such as [sklearn.linear_model.Ridge](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html), [sklearn.linear_model.Lasso](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html), [sklearn.svm.SVR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html).

Question:

The linked questions above discuss various reasons to standardize, center, or neither the predictor variables in regression settings. If I standardize the X matrix do I have to then standardize the y array? If I center the X matrix do I have to center the y array?

For either of those situations, would failing to standardize/center give me incorrect results?

Comment: NO, just because you standardized $X$ (or some of them) do not force you to standardize $y$ also.  Ask yourself: Why do I standarize? and see what the standarization is doing.  Otherwise see:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244507/what-algorithms-need-feature-scaling-beside-from-svm/252625#252625

Comment: So I know that for simple linear regression you do not need to standardize y (or x for that matter). I am asking about various other methods, like ridge, lasso, and SVR. It is not clear to me that the argument you linked applies to those methods.

Comment: They applies. ridge and lasso are not invariant, so needs standardization. But they only need it for $X$, not $y$ (but standardizin $y$ do no harm). I do not know about SVR, but the same principles apply.

Answer (score 3):

NO, just because you standardized the predictors $X$ do not force you to standardize the response $y$.  Ask yourself "Why do I standardize?" and see what the standardization is doing.  Some answers to that can be found at:  [What algorithms need feature scaling, beside from SVM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244507/what-algorithms-need-feature-scaling-beside-from-svm/252625#252625)   As to the additional question in comments: The arguments in my answer linked at above do also apply for ridge and lasso.  The arguments to standardize $X$ in those cases do not apply to $y$ (but if you want you can standardize $y$ too, it does no harm, but can complicate interpretations). 
 The same principles apply to SVR, but I do not know the answer in that case.