# Estimating number of clusters using Gap Statistics

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

Since my application is for streaming data, I chose to use BIRCH to create clusters. [BIRCH](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/459/han/papers/zhang96.pdf) doesn't produce high quality results, therefore it requires "global clustering step" to improve output clusters. Global clustering is often performed using Agglomerative clustering or K-Means.

I am trying to use BIRCH clustering results as input to Gap statistics in order to calculate number of clusters (K), which would be the input for K-Means as the Global step in BIRCH.

Instead of whole dataset, I am feeding Gap statistics with BIRCH subcluster centers as a new dataset. I am also testing this approach with [Pham method](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/PhamDN05-kmeans.pdf), which seems to give better results than Gap statistics.

One of the datasets I am using for testing is from [sklearn BIRCH examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_birch_vs_minibatchkmeans.html), 100K points around 100 centers. On Fig 1. Pham method guessed correctly number of clusters in this dataset (BIRCH produced 148 clusters; centers of those 148 clusters were the input points for Pham).

[image: Fig 1.]

Using Gap statistics I am always getting K=1 as a result. Following [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140711/why-does-gap-statistic-for-k-means-suggest-one-cluster-even-though-there-are-ob) I was changing the scale, but I am still unable to get good results. Results and dataset are shown on Fig 2. (Dataset is again made of subcluster centers produced by BIRCH)

[image: Gap statistics]

Do you have any suggestions how I can improve results for Gap Statistics?

Comment: Don't try to draw any conclusions from toy data.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Indeed.