# K Means and controlling cluster count

Tags: k-means

I am working on a problem of unsupervised classification.
The data samples are fairly random.
Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury of specifying the number of clusters.
I would like to use some criteria to automatically identify the number of clusters.

For example, assume there are distinctly 2 clusters in the data points and I use 3 clusters. Is there method to infer that 2 is the right number of clusters vs 3?

Comment: Search https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=k+means+count+validation.  Some threads provide answers, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140711.

Comment: If you "don't have the luxury of specifying the number of clusters" then how will you do k means cluster analysis at all?  Have you looked into hierarchical methods?