# Cumulative explained variance between scaled and unscaled data

Tags: pca, separation

I was writing a small piece of code to portray the difference between scaled and unscaled data when doing PCA and (as expected) I found that the separability of classes was better by doing the analysis over scaled data. I also plotted the cumulative explained variance ratio to portray the effect of less components explaining more variance and I found that the unscaled data had a steep value of cumulative explained variance for two components while for scaled data there was no component from which the next components only added marginally to the total explained variance ratio. These were the two plots I obtained, which seem contradictory for me

[image: cumulative explained variance ratio]
[image]

I expected the first plot to be the other way around (the scaled data being the one with the steep ascent in the cumulative explained variance ratio) but I'm not sure if this was only a mistake in my coding or something else I can't see.

This is the code that generated both plots

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# importing data
wine = load_wine()
X = wine.data
y = wine.target

# creating standardized version of data
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
Xs = scaler.transform(X)

# splitting into train and test
strat_splitter = StratifiedShuffleSplit(test_size=0.2, n_splits=1)

for train_index, test_index in strat_splitter.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    Xs_train, Xs_test = Xs[train_index], Xs[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]


# PCA of scaled and unscaled
unscaled_data_pca = PCA().fit(X_train)
scaled_data_pca = PCA().fit(Xs_train)

mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True)
fig.suptitle('Cumulative explained variance')

ax1.set(xlabel='$n_{comp}$', ylabel='$\%$ of cum. expl. variance', title = "scaled data", xticks = np.arange(1,13,1))
ax2.set(xlabel='$n_{comp}$', title = "unscaled data")

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace = 0.5)

for ax,data in [[ax1,scaled_data_pca], [ax2,unscaled_data_pca]]:
    rng = np.arange(0,data.n_components_+1, 1)
    csum = np.insert(data.explained_variance_ratio_, 0, 0)

    ax.plot(rng, np.cumsum(csum))
    ax.grid()


# using 2 components over scaled and unscaled data
projected_data_unscaled = PCA(2).fit_transform(X_train)
projected_data_scaled = PCA(2).fit_transform(Xs_train)

fig_proj, (ax_proj_scaled, ax_proj_unscaled) = plt.subplots(1,2)
fig_proj.suptitle("Proyected data")

for ax,data in [[ax_proj_scaled,projected_data_scaled], [ax_proj_unscaled,projected_data_unscaled]]:
    ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=pd.Categorical(y_train))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')


ax_proj_scaled.set_title("Projection of scaled data")
ax_proj_unscaled.set_title("Projection of unscaled data")


plt.show()
```

**EDIT**: Added graphs with the same scale and updated code

Comment: Part of the problem lies in the large distortion in your plot of the unscaled data: the relative scales on the axes differ by more than an order of magnitude. Redraw it with a 1:1 aspect ratio.  For an example of how profound the effect of such distortion can be, see the analogous set of scatterplots at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140723/919.

Comment: Care to extend your answer? I can't see clearly how can I extrapolate such ideas into my problem, mostly because a 1:1 scale renders both graphs unreadable.

Comment: The issue isn't whether you can read the graphs, but whether you interpret them correctly.  It should be enough to see the dramatic change effected by putting the scales on the same axes to understand what the issue is and resolve the contradiction you see.

Comment: I edited the post to see the same scales in both axis for both plots. I can't see anything with 1:1 ratio, and I don't understand why would I see something out of it

Comment: I don't see any change at all in your post.  We're discussing the "Proyected data" plots, not your "cumulative explained variance."  The scales aren't even in the same units of measurement in the latter, so it doesn't even make sense to equate them.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was confused and thinking about the wrong graph. I see now that 2D separability is gone for the unscaled case. Does this new result mean that since unscaled case has a single relevant component, you see them disposed nearly along a horizontal line?

Comment: Yes, that's right.