# We should normalize (or standardize) data before feature selection tests (t-test, related matrix, etc.)?

Tags: pca, t-test, feature-selection, factor-analysis, stepwise-regression

We should normalize (or standardize) data before these feature selection techniques? Which one for every technique? normalization of standardization?

- t-test
- Related matrix
- Stepwise
- PCA
- Factor analysis

Comment: I guess "scandalize" is a typo for "standardize". This question seems to be too broad. There are many threads here on the various definitions of normalization and standardization, and so you should read around to see what is here before asking for detailed answers on five different methods. (What is "related matrix"?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When conducting multiple regression, when should you center your predictor variables & when should you standardize them?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia)