Is there something like Z-score but for highly skewed distributions?
I'm analyzing my anki reviews answer times. Since I have a lot of data (over 14 years) with gaps between reviews and different study patterns I want to analyze this in cohorts.
One metric I want to create is my "confidence" in the answer: I want to know "how far from typical" particular answer is, but I want a metric that can be used consistently across the cohorts (and compared between them).
I found this answer on a similar question which suggest using percentiles, but I think percentiles don't capture exactly what I need - there are cohorts where my typical answer time is close to the median, but there are also ones where it's far off from the median.
Could I use for example (value - mode) / inter-quartile range for my metric? Or is there something similar I could use?
I know that my answer times are highly right-skewed.
Update:
As for why I want to use mode and not median as my typical value, and why I think percentile won't give me what I want:
I have over 8k words in my deck, cohorts span about 3 months to less than a year (it's varying - DBSCAN clustered to get separate periods of consistent reviews). This means majority of notes within each cohort will be well-known ones. But number of new notes added varies greatly between the cohorts - there are some where I didn't learn any new words, there are others where I added a lot. Since reviews of new notes will naturally take longer than my "typical" review time it will affect the median and percentiles, but not mode.
Since my cohorts are periods of consistent reviews, the review patterns (including answer times) will be more or less consistent within the cohort, but can vary a lot between the cohorts. So the mode is my "baseline" answer time that can be used across cohorts as a "zero point" of the metric - faster answers mean I'm more confident than on a "typical" note, longer - I'm less confident / I needed more time to recall the meaning.
Update 2:
I think I should also mention that I'll use it primarily for analyzing outliers, so I want my "typical" to mean "most answers are around that long", not "50% of the answers are less than that long".

Sure you can, there are many such methods you could use, more robust ones. Whether they make sense for this particular problem is a different question, one which is very much dependent on your data.

The problem is trying to come up with a one-number summary.  Instead I’d use the empirical cumulative distribution function and not try to oversimplify.  But to think in another direction consider (value - pseudomedian) / Gini’s mean difference.

Rereading the question I notice I skipped that you already thought about quantiles. „but I think percentiles don't capture exactly what I need“ Why isn't that what you need?

because of varying number of new words in cohorts. My review times on new words will be naturally longer than typical, and the (vastly) varying number of new words will influence median. I want something that is prone to that problem.

I guess it's not relevant to the real question but you might want to add a small amount of explanation of "anki reviews".

I have similar problems with understanding the topic. Asside from 'anki reviews', also the terms 'words in my deck' and 'notes' are unclear. And what sort of different cohorts do you have?

hmm, do you have any suggestion how to clarify that in my question, without introducing too much irrelevant information? Anki is SRS flashcards program, "word" or "note" is a single flashcard ("word" because I'm using it for language learning, should probably use consistently "note"). "deck" is a set of notes I'm analyzing. There are many answers on each note in my dataset. As for cohort I think my first update should clarify it already - a period of consistent reviews (separated by larger gaps with no reviews).

@260 asside from the clarifications, the recent turn in the question might potentially asked in a separate question. I missed the part "don't capture exactly what I need" and has a bit of a quick answer mainly addressing the title of the question "something like Z-score but for highly skewed distributions" (I believe the other answers did the same). Your problems with the z-score seem to be deeper and this question is a bit of an xy-problem. Instead of changing the question too much now it could be better to out it in a new question.

For that new question. What I would like to see is an explanation of the problem that allows me to understand and see the data without needing terminology outside of statistical terms. What is a 'SRS flashcards program'? What does reviewing it mean? Explain the process that generates the data. Also, add graphs and tables describing the data. Visualise the differences between the cohorts and the distribution of the data.

@SextusEmpiricus new question might be a good idea, but I'm not sure how to formulate it. Would "reasonable way of scaling deviation from mode" be OK?

To figure out what measure you want, you would have to more precisely define what you mean by "how far from typical".  In particular, you want to define "far" and "typical".
You suggest using the distance from mode, scaled by IQR. That might be right (although mode is an unusual choice). But I think the median would be a more common choice. Or a trimmed mean (the median is really just the maximally trimmed mean). Or, maybe, some other mean. Or, maybe, you want to take logs. Or something else. That's for "typical".
Then for "far", distance does seem fairly clear, but maybe not. Maybe you want the log of distance? Or something else. But probably not. But how do you want to scale? IQR is reasonable, but maybe you wan the whole range? Or the MAD? Or even the maximum value. Or some constant.
In the really wonderful book Statistics as Principled Argument Robert Abelson tries to get his readers away from "what can I do?" and "Can I do this?" questions to "What can I defend?" and "What is reasonable?" type questions.

wouldn't the question of scaling and distance be more-or-less answered by what I already said? I want a metric, that can be compared across cohorts. That's really it, numerical value itself has no other meaning for me. I chose mode, because with 8k words in total every cohort will have mostly known words, but each cohort will have varying number of new words (sometimes zero), which will affect the median. (updating my question to include information about why I think mode is the right choice)

No. There are a lot of choices of metric. Which one is right for you depends on your situation. So, my answer provides more like a guide to you figuring out which one is right. Maybe you need to account for new vs. known words.

Tried clarifying what I want in the updates to my original question. I need to adjust primarily for my review patterns that vary across cohorts, but yes, some sort of adjusting for the new vs known words may be nice. The problem is I have no idea how to even approach that (this only brings more questions like how to define "new"). That's why I define "typical" as "most answers are around this time" instead of "50% of answers are no longer than this time".

One option for a robust alternative to z-scores (robust to outliers and non-normal data) is $\frac{x_i - \text{median}(x)}{\text{MAD}(x)}$ where "MAD" is the median absolute deviation.
Here is some example R code:
data(mtcars);

mscore <- function(x) {
    (x - median(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / mad(x, constant = 1, na.rm = TRUE)
    }

mtcars$hp.mscore <- mscore(mtcars$hp);
summary(mtcars$hp.mscore);
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#> -1.3654 -0.5096  0.0000  0.4555  1.0962  4.0769

# You can interpret the transformed data as the number of MADs a value is away from the median
# For example:
med <- median(mtcars$hp);
MAD <- mad(mtcars$hp, constant = 1);
x1 <- mtcars$hp[1];
med;
#> [1] 123
MAD;
#> [1] 52
x1;
#> [1] 110
diff <- x1 - med;
diff;
#> [1] -13

# This sample is 0.25 MADs below the median
diff / MAD
#> [1] -0.25

Created on 2024-11-14 with reprex v2.0.2

Lastly, note the stats::mad function by default uses constant = 1.4826.  I think this is supposed to make the transformed value nearly identical to a z-score if the data is normally distributed.  However, I personally prefer the interpretation to be the "Number of MADs a value is away from the median".  To get this interpretation, set constant = 1
Recall a z-score is interpreted as "the number of standard deviations a value is from the mean".  In contrast, the "m-score" above is interpreted as the number of MADs a value is away from the median.


Glad to see your comment on the multiplicative constant. I agree; if I want a median absolute deviation, I want a median absolute deviation, not an attempt at estimating the SD. More generally, I add some caution on either version. In very skewed data, it's quite possible for the MAD to be 0 and then it's useless for this purpose (and several others).

Moreover, in what sense is this robust? Large outliers pull up the mean and SD alike and when all is done (value $-$ median) / IQR is likely to be more sensitive to such outliers than the analogue using mean and SD. If this is what is wanted, fine and good.

this makes sense if my "typical" is median, but this gives me an idea what I could potentially use: if I define "typical" as mode, would using average absolute deviation from mode in a similar way make sense?

You could follow the approach of Cox-Snell residuals.
Cox, David R.; Snell, E. Joyce (1968). "A general definition of residuals". Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series B. 30 (2): 248–275. link
Instead of z-values you will be using quantiles.
The exact approach depends on your assumptions about the distribution, or when there is a lack of such assumptions the approach to estimate it.

This is very similar to your reference

I found this answer on a similar question which suggest using percentiles, but I think percentiles don't capture exactly what I need

It is unclear why this doesn't capture what you need

there are cohorts where my typical answer time is close to the median, but there are also ones where it's far off from the median.

With percentiles you capture this, they tell "how far from typical" a particular answer is.
Is it maybe that you want to have the distribution variable from cohort to cohort and not capture the between cohort variations?

I'm not sure I understand "Is it maybe that you want to have the distribution variable from cohort to cohort and not capture the between cohort variations?" correctly, but it might be exactly what I want - updated my question. I want to compare answers on particular notes, while adjusting for my varying review patterns (i.e. varying "typical" review time across the cohorts).

@260 A z-score makes comparisons by standardisation and alternatives will do this similar. It appears that you do not want standardisation, or at least not based on treating all the data the same. In that case you can either treat everything one by one (apply the standardisation method to each seperate cohort individually), or you need some intelligent way to transform the cohorts such that they can be treated together. Potentially you might fit quantiles as a function of some variable as here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/572407/

what I want to achieve is some sort of standarization within the cohort, that can be compared per-note across cohorts (I think about comparing note's average within-cohort scores, but if I can compare non-aggregated data directly it would be even better).
