Multinomial logistic regression analysis of the wine dataset. Very large standard errors
I am learning logistic regression with R and I was testing the dataset wine from the library rattle.
library ( rattle )
data ( wine )

I used the following code to standardize my variables:
features <- wine[, -1]
target <- wine$Type   

features_norm <- scale(features)

wine_norm <- as.data.frame(features_norm) 
wine_norm$Type <- target  

I performed stepwise selection twice, one for the model fitted to the data without any modifications and one with the data standardized. The results are the following:
summary(stepwise_model)
Call:
multinom(formula = Type ~ Flavanoids + Alcohol + Proline + Hue, 
    data = wine)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept) Flavanoids   Alcohol     Proline       Hue
2   408.93665  -19.93331 -32.79623 -0.18819766 200.13502
3   -58.70074  -75.83563  20.52408 -0.04340099 -88.04955

Std. Errors:
  (Intercept) Flavanoids   Alcohol     Proline        Hue
2   0.1655570   3.207194 0.8278404 0.008278356 0.51816676
3   0.1058972   0.159733 1.3959121 0.026907262 0.05795584

Residual Deviance: 0.9549102 
AIC: 20.95491 

summary(stepwise_model_norm)
Call:
multinom(formula = Type ~ Flavanoids + Alcohol + Proline + Hue, 
    data = wine_norm)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept) Flavanoids   Alcohol   Proline       Hue
2   -10.37814  -22.53536 -40.46853 -75.51493  57.92905
3   -71.76456  -90.92047  20.96044 -16.72466 -21.08734

Std. Errors:
  (Intercept) Flavanoids   Alcohol   Proline       Hue
2    9.028637   16.88702  33.99191  56.27516  43.30412
3  114.794563  136.45769 147.84533 156.41286 190.13100

Residual Deviance: 0.4184597 
AIC: 20.41846 

I find that the coefficients in both models are a bit too big (specially in the first one). However, the most surprising thing is that standard errors in the second model are very large compared to the actual size of the coefficients (much larger proportionally than they are in the first one).
I looked at the correlation matrix and some of them are a bit high, but it should not be very problematic I think. Should I check for more complex relations using VIFs? Or do you think it can be due to quasi-perfect separation?
I created boxplots of each variable by type, and they do not seem very well separated. However, looking at Flavanoids + Proline by type, they seem to divide the data into 3 clear clusters, one for each type.

I am a bit out of ideas and looking for some recommendations.
Thanks

Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please edit the question to show the code that you used to standardize the data? It's best to edit the question rather than respond in a comment, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted. Note that the magnitudes of coefficients will depend on the scales of the predictors, so it can be dangerous to conclude that "coefficients are a bit too big" without considering the scales. Also, please look at this page for reasons to avoid automated model selection, particularly via forward stepwise methods.

Huge coefficients and runaway standard errors are indeed a tell-tale sign of (quasi)complete separation.

Another possible problem is collinearity.

@EdM Thank you! I added some extra information. Since the standardized data is monstly contained in [-3,3] coefficients like -90 seemed a bit too large, but I was more worried about the standard errors being almost double the size of the coefficients for class 3.

"the standard errors explode in the model fitted to standarized data." what does this mean?

@SextusEmpiricus I meant that the errors in the model
multinom(formula = Type ~ Flavanoids + Alcohol + Proline + Hue,  data = wine_norm) (logistic regression using the data after standarization)
are very large with respect to the size of the coefficients ( when I use data=wine they are smaller proportionally to the size of the coefficients)

How do you determine the errors? Normalizing the features shouldn't change anything. It is just a linear transformation.

@SextusEmpiricus The standard errors provided by the code in R. Affine transformations do not change (quasi)-compete separation or correlations. However, it could happen that in the original data collinearity was hidden due to huge differences in scale (as an example, x_2=x_1+10000 and x_1 are perfectly correlated but it won't be a problem to invert the design matrix), when we center the data, suddenly, the collinearity is clear and causes usntability.

@student ah, I see, the errors of the coefficients. I was thinking about the errors of the predictions (which shouldn't change). Centering the data can have a large influence on the coefficient values and their errors because the correlations change. The coefficients can even flip sign. There is another question about that.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425082/standardization-of-variables-and-collinearity

Large coefficients and standard errors

I looked at the correlation matrix and some of them are a bit high,


standard errors in the second model are very large

Correlated variables can explain large coefficients (and errors). This happens if the types are explained by a difference between two coefficients.
For example two features like phenols and flavanoids might correlate from wine to wine, but in some type a slight difference could occur. Then the difference between the two features can be used to predict and possibly this can relate to large coefficient values and errors.
The two images below illustrate why the errors can be large.

The first image depicts the regression as a projection onto a subspace created by vectors whose components relate to the values of each wine for a particular feature.


The vectors in this subspace are sort of creating a coordinate system. Below we see that plane when we look at it head on. The cloud of points display how values could vary from sample to sample. The points don't change much in the original space. But the coordinates created by the correlated vectors are very narrow and close to each other. We see that small differences in the location of a point can coincide with a large change in the coordinates of the coordinate space created by the features.



Separation

Or do you think it can be due to quasi-perfect separation

A sharp seperation, or complete separation is another cause.
The differences in features/parameters between two types can be small, but those differences is not what the coefficients express. The coefficients give the slope of the class probability as function of the parameters. Smaller differences actually coincide with larger slopes.
If the boundary/difference is small then the change of probability for a small change of the coefficients is high.
The following image may show this more clearly. What the model does is sort of overlay a class probability as function of the parameters. If the class probabability changes quickly over a small distance, then thisbrelates to a large slope and large coefficients.

