# Interaction term and main effect multicollinearity

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

If I have the predictors $X$, $Y$, and $XY$ to fit a linear regression model. Won't  I be increasing the standard error of the regression coefficients? This is because $XY$ is collinear with $X$ and $Y$ correct?

Comment: Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia

Comment: XY is not necessarily highly related to any linear combination of X and Y; it depends on the circumstances. Standard errors might well go down.

Comment: It turns out our site has a great many posts discussing collinearity and interaction: see [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multicol*+interaction).