# Do percent variables need to be scaled for machine learning?

Tags: normalization, standardization, percentage, variable, feature-scaling

I have 101 independent variables in a logistic regression predictive model. 55 variables are continuous and 46 are categorical one-hot encoded. 5 of the 55 continuous variables are expressed as percents (values ranging from 0.05 to 0.90).

For the 50 continuous variables, I am experimenting with applying normalization (MinMaxScaler) or standardization (StandardScaler). I am unsure what to do with the 5 percent variables.

Do I need to apply normalization, standardization, or leave the percent variables as they are without scaling them?

Comment: Could you make it more specific? The answer depends on many different factors.

Comment: @Tim can you give me an example where it wouldn’t be needed and where scaling would be needed (and which scaling method to use)?

Comment: Please make it more specific.

Comment: @Tim Updated. Let me know if more detail is needed. Not sure what else I can add since the answer will be “it depends” anyway. I’m interested in learning about the scenarios when scaling is or isn’t appropriate.

Comment: See  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks for sharing, but that post doesn’t answer my question.

Comment: Short answer is there is nothing you have said that indicates a need for scaling, that is a very seldom need. Unless you can tell us some more detail indicating a need, the default should be to let the variables as is.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I’ll accept that as the answer if you post it. I tried scaled and unscaled percentages and performance was roughly the same, so I came to the conclusion that scaling wasn’t needed, at least for my problem.