# Does normalizing the design matrix change predictions?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I'm trying to show that $\hat{y} = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = \tilde{X}(\tilde{X}^T\tilde{X})^{-1}\tilde{X}^Ty$, where each column in $\tilde{X}$ is normalized by subtracting the mean and dividing by standard deviation. Is this even true?

Comment: No it is not true

Comment: See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia