# Should I use standardised or unstandardised beta coefficient in this scenario?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients

I am running a regression on Tax payment and investment. Tax payment is numerical and investment is categorical like, number of projects carried out. When I run the regression the a unstandardised beta coefficient is very very small, close to zero, but standardised coefficient is about 0.348. The p value is less than 0.05 and therefore statistically significant. Appreciate your quick response as I am running out of time in completing the thesis.

Best regards
Sudhuna

Answer (score 1):

- You need to scale the data only for certain kinds of models, for numerical reasons. For example, when using regularization. If you are using a regression model without regularization, or random effects, you don't need it.
- In some cases, you can use scaling if it makes the parameters easier to interpret.
- Scaling does not affect your results (for standard regression, as said above), predictions, and $p$-values would stay the same. The only thing that would change is the scale of the parameters because they reflect the scale of the features, for example, if you used a feature in minutes vs hours, in the second case the parameter for it would be 60 times smaller.

See also [When conducting multiple regression, when should you center your predictor variables & when should you standardize them?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29781/35989)